# Symfony Asset configuration

Tags: css, twig, assets, symfony

I just started to use Symfony 3.0.6 framework and I can't understand the using of Assets. 
I'm trying to add my custom css files to the twig template but it is not working.

I'm running Wamp64 local server and my css is in:

```
C:\wamp64\www\rating\web\custom.css
```

**rating** is the base directory of my project.

I'we done configuration according this page: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#cookbook-assetic-including-css

And here is twig code:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('custom.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
```

When I try to load css from the web it is working without problem.

I can't understand where is the problem. I search web but nothing helped and I'm really mad of it.

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony, assets are by default added to your **app** resources or **bundle** resources. Plainly adding them to your web directory is considered bad practice, because it makes your bundle dependant on your project setup.

In your case, add custom.css to *C:\wamp64\www\rating\src\AppBundle\Resources\public\your_subdirectories_here*

Then, run the following command:
`php app/console assets:install --symlink`

Symfony will then publish your assets to *C:\wamp64\www\rating\web\bundles\app*

After doing that, you can access your CSS file using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/app/your_subdirectories_here/custom.css') }}">
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the basic problem is that custom.css is not loaded to the browser.

Comment: Forgot to add that part, apologies. Re-check the answer :) Also, you might find this article interesting:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html

Comment: As I write earlier I don't know where the problem is but my css still isn't loaded to the browser. Even after following your advice.

Comment: Did your CSS file end up in web/bundles/app after executing `php app/console assets:install --symlink`? If so, the provided twig code should work (after modifying the your_subdirectories_here part of course). If not, check if custom.css is added to src/AppBundle/public.

Comment: Yes the full path is now: 
C:\wamp64\www\rating\web\bundles\app\custom.css

And my Twig command:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/app/custom.css') }}">

Comment: Then the code should be completely valid... Please check if your web server has access to the css file (also check if the web server is allowed to follow symbolic links)

Comment: Yes, when I put the file path to the browser I see my css file. I also tried to view my page on different browsers but there is no difference.

Comment: When you put the file path in your browser, you're not accessing the file through your web server, but through your local file system. Please check if you can access the file through your web server and if it is allowed to follow symbolic links.

Comment: When I try this: http://rating:8080/bundles/app/custom.css. I get the symfony error that there is no route found...

Comment: If http://rating:8080 refers to your web directory, then apparently your web server cannot access the file either because it can't follow symbolic links or because the permissions are not configured correctly. If you don't want to go through the hassle of configuring your web server, you could try executing `php app/console assets:install` to see if installing assets as hard copies works. Otherwise, you're going to have to configure your file permissions / web server access.

Comment: Thanks for info. At least I know where the problem is and can search it.

Comment: Hey good job on finding the issue! Turned out to be something completely different than we thought :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to symfony and I configured my local alias according one online tutorial and there it wasn't configured well.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP):*

I found where the problem was. When I was configuring my local alias (rating:8080) I added this path

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/rating/web/app_dev.php"
  ServerName rating
</VirtualHost>
```

instead of

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/rating/web"
  ServerName rating
</VirtualHost>
```

So when I call rating:8080 from my browser it goes directly to php and not to .htacces. As result the route wasn't configured what is logic :)

As last I have to configure my .htacces file because the default redirecting was to app.php and not app_dev.php (simply every where inside the file change the app.php to app_dev.php).

Now everything works perfectly.